# Using variables in input parameters

Tags: python, input

I am trying to write a python script that will use the value of a variable within the input query. I want the output to look something like this (with user input in italics):

Hello, what is your name? *John*

Hello John, where are you from? *New York*

The print() function can do something similar to what I want, with the ability to switch between strings and variables, but I can't figure out how to do the same with input(). For example I can write:

```
name = 'John'
location = 'New York'
print('My name is', name, 'and I am from', location)
```

and recieve:

My name is John and I am from New York

but I can't write

```
input('Hello', name, 'where are you from?')
```

P.S. I am not writing anything that will be published so I don't need to use the raw_input() function.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you have written.
Also can you show us the output that you are getting (including any error messages) and what you expect the output to be. (PS - in general - when asking for help - you always need to provide all these things... which is why you are being voted down by other people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%` operator. It's also called the [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) operator in this case.

```
>>> name = input('What is your name? ')
What is your name? 'Thomas'
>>> location = input('Hello %s, where are you from? ' % name)
Hello Thomas, where are you from? 'Virginia'
>>> print("Your name is %s and you are from %s." % (name, location))
Your name is Thomas and you are from Virginia.
```

Comment: Fantastic, this does exactly what I want. Thanks.